# Automatic Refactoring of Monolith

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, automated-refactoring

We have a rather large-ish monolithic software we would like to refactor at a larger scale. First step will be to derive several artefacts, which can be compiled independently. Given the size of the application we would like to automate that as much as possible.

An example:

```
+ package1
|    |
|    + Service1
|
+ package2
|    |
|    + Service2
|
+ interfacepackage
```

Assuming, `Service1` is only used from within `package1`, it should not be touched. Assuming `Service2` is used from `Service1` I would like to automatically generate a minimal interface for `Service2`, put that interface in the package `interfacepackage` and change the dependency within `Service1` to the interface.

Doing this manually would be no trouble at all. Both Idea and Eclipse provide semi-automatic refactorings, but we would like to formulate them as meta-rules. I had hopes, that either eclipse or intellij have a programmatic interface to define such rules, but I have not been able to find them yet.

I have even found the eclipse refactoring scripts but these seem to be restricted to refactorings of named classes, so if I knew all services which should be refactored, eclipse refactoring scripts would help but not if I want to define conditions on classes to be refactored.

Where should I look for a solution?

**Clarification: Comment: So what's your problem?**

We have a high 3 digit number of services which make up this monolith. These are in approx. 20 different packages. The whole software is approaching 1 million lines of code. My problem is simply the size. Doing refactorings manually could take months, we might miss something doing it manually. Also, de-tangeling the services is the first step only. So we are expecting a lot of similar refactorings applied down the road.

Comment: "Doing this manually would be no trouble at all" So what's the problem?

Comment: You might write an Eclipse plug-in that contributes a customized [refactoring](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-06/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ltk_core_refactoring_refactoringContributions.html?cp=2_1_1_110) for that.

Comment: @howlger would that be automatically applicable to the complete source tree? Remember, I do not want to individually apply the refactoring to a single class but to let the system identify all classes which are eligible to the refactoring.

Comment: @Jonathan Sure, you might write it e.g. to be applicable on a project or source folder.

Comment: Sounds like you either need to script this (use a scripting language) or write yourself a plugin. But please be aware - going into "microservices heaven" you can often end up in "microservices hell".... do you really need to split the monolith into 100+ services? How are you going to then manage those? And the dependencies? And the build / release / deploy pipelines? Will you be better off in the end?

Comment: @vikingsteve we are not going for microservice. In lack of a better word, we are going for "modulith". 

We could certainly go for a script but that script would be required to parse the java code. My hopes are to access the meta-model, the IDEs already build up in the background. I will try the idea of howlger and go for a refactoring plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA has an "open api" that can be used for plugin development.

The advantage is that IntelliJ parses the java code, and the "meta model" is available to you as a plugin author.

In IntelliJ, the "AST" model refers to the "Abstract Syntax Tree". This structure is invaluable for plugins that do refactorings.

You can easily see the package structure, class names, code, and so on.

https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started.html

Note! Java functionality for plugin development has been externalised as a plugin.

https://blog.jetbrains.com/platform/2019/06/java-functionality-extracted-as-a-plugin/

Please also have a look at my own plugins on github, where I have posted the source code.

https://github.com/Steve-Murphy/unencapsulate-plugin

Comment: Thanks for your input. As we are mainly using IDEA in our company, I would actually prefer that solution to the eclipse solution. I'll come back here once I had time to take a peek.

Comment: Plugin development is extremely powerful and can be a lifesaver in tasks like this. Good luck!

Comment: Also see this plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9345-jdt-astview

Comment: Do you by chance know, how to access the Java-specific PSI implementation within IDEA? They are not included after setting up the plugin as described in the howto. Also the jdt-plugin seems to use the eclipse-API to do the actual parsing.

Comment: Never mind. Issue here is that the java-functionality got externalized in idea 2019.2: https://blog.jetbrains.com/platform/2019/06/java-functionality-extracted-as-a-plugin/. As long as the documentation has not been updated... would you mind enriching your answer for future reference?